# Perl regular expression pattern length

Tags: regex, perl

I want to search one particular pattern with in one string but of specific length (maximum length is 20).
Example:

string:

```
hellokkkkkkkkkkhellokhellokkhellokkkkk
```

regex:

```
/(hello.*?hello.*?hello)/
```

but it gives me following pattern

loc:0 to 26

```
hellokkkkkkkkkkhellokhello
```

But what i want is only the second pattern (means `hellokhellokkhello`) which is of length < 20..
Any suggestions?

Comment: @TLP: sorry, the escape characters were placed I don't know why :-(

Comment: @M42 Ok, it just looked strange.

Answer (score 4):

To get overlapping matches, use a [look-ahead](http://p3rl.org/perlre#Look-Around-Assertions).

```
my $string = 'hellokkkkkkkkkkhellokhellokkhellokkkkk';
say for
    grep { length($_) < 20 }
    $string =~ /(?=(hello.*?hello.*?hello))/g;
```